# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.6.2

Tags: nginx, berkshelf

I am getting this error on our private berkshelf server and this is what I have in the logs.

```
2017/05/15 04:58:07 [error] 1571#0: *312936 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.75.1.169, server: radberks.datacenter.radiangroupinc.net, request: "GET /universe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:26200/universe", host: "radberks"
2017/05/15 04:58:34 [error] 1571#0: *312951 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.75.1.169, server: radberks.datacenter.radiangroupinc.net, request: "GET /universe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:26200/universe", host: "radberks"
2017/05/15 08:57:04 [err
~
```

Here is my conf file

```
# cat nginx.conf user nginx; worker_processes 4; error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; pid /var/run/nginx.pid; events { worker_connections 1024; } http { include /etc/nginx/mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream; access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; sendfile on; tcp_nopush on; tcp_nodelay on; keepalive_requests 100; keepalive_timeout 65;
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of the .conf file where the route is defined?

Comment: Here is my conf file     # cat nginx.conf
user nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;


  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  keepalive_requests 100;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

Comment: Is that exactly how it is in your `nginx.conf`? If you have it in one line and it has that `# cat nginx.conf` statement pasted at the beginning, the whole thing is one long comment, which would cause a problem.